# Python LDAP "Can't contact LDAP server"

Tags: python, ldap

I'm trying to run an LDAP server on my local host with the following code:

```
import ldap
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://127.0.0.1')
l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
USERNAME = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org"
PASSWORD = "pass"
l.simple_bind_s(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

I get the error: "Can't contact LDAP server"

Comment: Are you running a LDAP server on your local machine where this script is executed?

Comment: Nope. This was the only piece of code I could find.

Comment: Basic knowledge of IP addresses, `127.0.0.1` == Always the machine you're sitting on. It's a built-in mechanic in the IP address range to point "back at yourself". Try using the LDAP servers IP address, that will most likely fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are not **running** a ldap-server from your code, you are trying to connect to an **existing** ldap server.

You have to set up and **run** an ldap-server on your machine **then** connect to it.

Like open-ldap for windows:
[OpenLdap](http://www.userbooster.de/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx)

or for Ubuntu (Linux):
[Create OpenLdap on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)

If there is an existing server you have to enter the correct IP-Address

Answer (score 0):

Try using username as **admin@example.org**
and check the logs at **/mnt/var/log/hive** (if it's a hive authentication)

Also, try accessing the ldapserver from UI.

**Apache Directory Studio
Version: 2.0.0.v20170904-M13**

Comment: This should be a comment not answer